# Has Israel's polity ever had a debate on "feminist foreign policy"?

Tags: israel, foreign-policy, feminism

A number of countries [have advocated and declared](https://www.unwomen.org/sites/default/files/2022-09/Brief-Feminist-foreign-policies-en_0.pdf) (pdf) to run a "feminist foreign policy".

> As of July 2022, this list includes
> Sweden (2014), Canada (2017), France (2019), Mexico
> (2020), Spain (2021), Luxembourg (2021), Germany
> (2021) and Chile (2022) [...]

and the piece discusses the debates in a few other countries, although the declaration has sometimes been [criticized](https://www.hrw.org/news/2022/03/23/what-do-canada-france-germany-and-sweden-owe-afghan-women) as being without much substance.

I'm curious if there has been any discussion on this subject in Israel. Have there been any public debate or proposals to declare a "feminist foreign policy" there?

Comment: careful with the f-word here :) also, good question, +1

Comment: Not VTC, I rely on you to fix the problems in this question or delete it yourself. The question answers itself in more than one way; 1. The list of countries lacks most liberal countries in the world. 2. Pragraph three is a good enough answer.

Comment: Let me guess: a rapidly growing religious community has a right to vote. They execute it. Hm, why leadership does not ignore them? Hard to answer.

Comment: Also Israel has a proportional representation electoral system that often ends up giving some fairly extremist religious parties the balance of power.  Not having an explicitly stated "feminist foreign policy" is an easy concession to those parties that won't get you excluded from a coalition.

Comment: In a country as big as Israel probably there was some discussion somewhere at some point. Probably even in Russia there might have been such a proposal. It just didn't live long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Israel is a member of the [Feminist Foreign Policy Plus Group](https://www.gendersecurityproject.com/post/feminist-foreign-policy-plus-group-political-declaration) which met on September 20, 2023 at the United Nations and issued a policy [declaration](https://www.government.nl/documents/diplomatic-statements/2023/09/20/political-declaration-on-feminist-approaches-to-foreign-policy) which

> affirmed the importance of "the empowerment of women and girls in all their diversity" as crucial for the full implementation  of the [Beijing Declaration and Platform for Action](https://www.unwomen.org/en/digital-library/publications/2015/01/beijing-declaration), the promotion, protection, and fulfillment of human rights and peace and security, as well as the achievement of the SDGs and combatting the "feminization of poverty."

The group comprises Albania, Argentina, Belgium, Canada, Chile, Colombia, Costa Rica, France, Germany, Israel, Liberia, Luxembourg, Mexico, Mongolia, Rwanda, Spain, Sweden, The Kingdom of the Netherlands and Tunisia, and representatives of these governments met for this declaration as part of the 78th session of the UN General Assembly.

It's not clear how serious Israel's commitment is; Freya Thompson of the London School of Economics has criticised Israel's commitment to women's health, particularly in Gaza. ([Why Feminist Foreign Policy doesn’t have all the answers to the humanitarian crisis in Israel-Palestine](https://blogs.lse.ac.uk/internationaldevelopment/2023/10/31/why-feminist-foreign-policy-doesnt-have-all-the-answers/), LSE Blogs, 31 October 2023) But there is some kind of belief in feminist policy in Israel's government even if it hasn't been translated into action.